# Input empty give 0

Tags: vue.js

hopefully you can help me. I want that if input remains empty, it is assigned a value of 0. At the moment of loading my modal the value is 0, if my input is focused, 0 is deleted. If I go to the next input I do not want any input to remain empty

```js
onFocus() {
    this.efectivo = '';
},
onFocus1() {
    this.tarjeta = '';
},
```

```html
<td style="background-color: #CEECF5">
  <input name="txtd" @focus="onFocus1" v-bind:min="0" v-model="tarjeta" type="number">
</td>
<td style="background-color: #CEECF5">
  <input name="txte" @focus="onFocus2" v-bind:min="0" v-model="vales" type="number">
</td>
```

[image: my 2 inputs]

[image: when writing with the numeric keyboard, the 0 remains at the beginning]

Comment: List already shared

Comment: show all your code.... a [MCVE]

Comment: I already put the html code

Comment: watch for `efectivo` and `tarjeta`, if `newValue !== 0 && !newValue` is true, then  `this.efectivo=0` or `this.tarjeta=0`

Comment: that where would you put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) whenever you're tempted to use a watch, consider using a `computed` instead:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    t: 0
  }),
  computed: {
    test: {
      get() {
        return Number(this.t)
      },
      set(val) {
        this.t = Number(val) || 0
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onBlur() {
      this.$refs.test.value = this.test
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="test"
         type="number"
         min="0"
         max="100"
         placeholder="0"
         ref="test"
         @blur="onBlur" />
  <pre v-html="{test}" />
</div>
```

The above follows the Store pattern (one source of truth), where `data` acts as a local store for your computed property.
If you use Vuex, you should (obviously) read `test` value from the store and commit the mutation in the setter.
If you're not using Vuex but still want to export your `data` prop so that external components can react to its change, you can use the shiny new `Vue.observable()`, added in `v2.6`:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const store = Vue.observable({ test: 0 });

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    test: {
      get() {
        return Number(store.test)
      },
      set(val) {
        store.test = Number(val) || 0
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onBlur() {
      this.$refs.test.value = this.test
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="test"
         type="number"
         min="0"
         max="100"
         placeholder="0"
         ref="test"
         @blur="onBlur" />
  <pre v-html="{test}" />
</div>
```

Now your `store` const can live in a different file, can be imported/exported and you can listen to its changes in any other component by using it inside a `computed` property.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems you'd like to implement one input can't be empty when lose focus, and if the value of the input is empty, you'd like to assign zero to it.

I think uses watch will be one option like below demo:

**Updated**: the value of the input will be one string,

So for first solution: if you'd like to trim the leading zero, uses the modifier=number of `v-model` like `v-model.number='test1'`.

For second solution: convert it to `this.test2 = Number(this.test2)` manually.

```js
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
    return {
      test1:0, //uses v-model, actually :value and @input, @input will occurs when text content of input is changed
      test2: 0, //uses :value and @change, @change will occurs when lose focus or press 'enter/return',
    }
  },
  watch: {
    test1: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== 0 && !newVal) this.test1 = 0
    },
    test2: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal !== 0 && !newVal) this.test2 = 0
      this.test2 = Number(this.test2)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateTest2: function (e) {
      this.test2 = e.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        Directly assign 0 when empty: <input v-model.number="test1" type="number">
        <pre>Test: {{test1}}</pre>
        Assign 0 if input is empty when loses focus:<input :value="test2" @change="updateTest2($event)" type="number">
        <pre>Test: {{test2}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me to directly assign 0 when it is empty. Good, but now how could it be so that when it is encrypted, the 0 does not stay at the beginning

Comment: If I understand your new requirements correctly, please see the updated snippet.

Comment: I just uploaded an image with what happens. Thanks

Comment: not sure what that image means. could you explain it?

Comment: add a new image on initial post

Comment: if I write with the numeric keyboard on the input the initial 0 remains. example 0510 which should be 510

Comment: Don't answer multiple questions into one. You're not here to code for OP. You're here to help OP and anyone with the initial same problem understand how to solve it. Bottom like: if you answer how to fix leading zeros here, it won't be indexed and found by anyone searching for a solution to it. Please follow [SO] guidelines. @Christian, please ask another question about your second problem.

Comment: I already put another post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511925/the-initial-0-is-left-in-input-with-numeric-keyboard